# create an array based on grouping (and conditions) from an array

Tags: arrays, performance, julia

So, I have the following array (structured as `Array{Tuple{Int,Float64,Int,Int},1}` but it can also be an Array of Arrays) and where the first element of the tuple is an `ID` and the second is a number indicating a cost. What i want to do is to group by `ID` and then take the cost difference between the cheapest and the second cheapest cost for such `ID`, if there is no second cost, the cost difference should be `typemax(Float64) -firstcost`. Regarding the third and fourth elements of the `Tuple`, I want to keep those of the `firstcost` (or minimum cost in that sense).
Example of what I have

```
(1, 223.2, 2, 2)
(1, 253.2, 3, 2)
(2, 220.0, 4, 6)
(3, 110.0, 1, 4)
(3, 100.0, 3, 8)
```

Example of what I want:

```
(1, 30.0, 2, 2)
(2, typemax(Float64)-220.0, 4, 6)
(3,10.0, 3, 8)
```

Comment: Are you using DataFrames.jl? It is similar to Python's pandas, and is probably well suited for these kind of problems.

Comment: Hi! I am not using dataframes, I am working with algorithms so I think it would be more struggle to use a dataframe.

Comment: Ok, makes sense

Comment: That said, there is a `groupby` function in Dataframes.jl, which is exactly what you need, so maybe it is not much overhead to use it after all?

Comment: yeah I am using that now but it is a last resort, and I am looking for improvements :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
A = [(1, 223.2, 2, 2), (1, 253.2, 3, 2), (2, 220.0, 4, 6), (3, 110.0, 1, 4), (3, 100.0, 3, 8)]

function f(a)
    aux(b::Vector) = (b[1][1], (length(b) == 1 ? typemax(Float64) : b[2][2]) - b[1][2], b[1][3:4]...)
    sort([aux(sort(filter(x -> x[1] == i, a))) for i in Set(map(first, a))])
end

@show f(A)
```

Comment: Thanks, works wonderful with the example, I'll try it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

There's `SplitApplyCombine.jl`, which implements (unsurprisingly) a split-apply-combine logic like that found in DataFrames. This is an example where I would stay away from simple one-liners / short solution and write things out more explicitly in the interest of making the code readable and understandable if someone else (or you yourself in a few months time!) reads it:

```
julia> tups = [(1, 223.2, 2, 2)
       (1, 253.2, 3, 2)
       (2, 220.0, 4, 6)
       (3, 110.0, 1, 4)
       (3, 100.0, 3, 8)]
5-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Float64,Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 223.2, 2, 2)
 (1, 253.2, 3, 2)
 (2, 220.0, 4, 6)
 (3, 110.0, 1, 4)
 (3, 100.0, 3, 8)

julia> using SplitApplyCombine

julia> function my_fun(x) # function to apply
           if length(x) == 1
               return (x[1][1], typemax(Float64) - x[1][2], x[1][3], x[1][4])
           else
               return (x[1][1], -diff(sort(getindex.(x, 2), rev = true)[1:2]), x[1][4])
           end
       end
my_fun (generic function with 1 method)

julia> [my_fun(x) for x in group(first, tups)] # apply function group wise
3-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Any,Int64,Vararg{Int64,N} where N},1}:
 (2, Inf, 4, 6)
 (3, [10.0], 4)
 (1, [30.0], 2)
```

If performance is a concern you might want to think about `my_fun` and do some profiling to see if and how you can improve it - the only thing I've done here is to use `diff` to subtract the first from the second element of the sorted array to avoid sorting twice.